# Controlling High voltage devices with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, rpi.gpio, relay

Can I control high voltage (here 5V) to power a led lamp and a fan(both operating at 5v) from Raspberry Pi GPIO only using a transistor . Or should I isolate both the circuits using a relay or octo-coupler

Answer (score -1):

yes, you CAN just use a npn transistor:

[image: schematic]

see [more info here](https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits)

but if you want to use A pnp transistor:

I think a voltage divider with a pnp transistor might work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f61QFR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

you probably just want to go with the npn circuit, though.

Comment: Obviously you haven't tried this

Comment: No, not the pnp voltage-divider circuit. I adapted that from another website. but I have used the npn one.